# Download Video from Granicus

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-capture

I spoke for a couple of minutes at a recent city council meeting. I want to download the video so that I can grab my portion of the video and post it to social media. The city uses some provider called Granicus.  Here is the url:

[URL to Entire Video](http://wilmington.granicus.com/videos/4979/player?autoplay=0)

Can somebody please help me? I have tried downloading VLC, but it fails to open the stream.

Answer (score 5):

As of November 2022, this new format appears to work; instead of "archive-media" in the domain, change to "archive-video," drop the port number and "OnDemand"

http://archive-video.granicus.com/wilmington/wilmington_d31da0f6-c191-4b9d-a768-efe97d215f4f.mp4

Comment: Thanks for the update! I did notice that if you try to download the file in Microsoft Edge you get an error about not being able to download the file securely.  However, it worked in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for a Tennessee Legislature Committee Meeting as well. To find the mp4 file, go to the regular viewer. In my case, this was the link:
http://tnga.granicus.com/MediaPlayer.php?view_id=474&clip_id=21699

There you have a subdomain: tnga (Tennessee General Assembly)
and a clip ID: 21699
Use that to create a new URL:

http://tnga.granicus.com/videos/21699/player

In that new URL, if you go to the page source, you can find code like this:

```
    <div class="fp-player"><video preload="none" class="fp-engine" webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true" src="blob:http://tnga.granicus.com/93951813-05c0-4777-b059-8e4549dbb7b7" x-webkit-airplay="allow">
    <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="//archive-stream.granicus.com/OnDemand/_definst_/mp4:tnga/tnga_506e8e41-acbd-42df-852e-51a679841158.mp4/playlist.m3u8">
    </video>
```

That part that begins with the subdomain "tnga" and ends with ".mp4" is what you use to create your link to download the file. In this case, the download link is:

http://archive-media.granicus.com:443/OnDemand/tnga/tnga_506e8e41-acbd-42df-852e-51a679841158.mp4

The part after OnDemand/ is the same subdomain used in other places, in this case, "tnga".

Answer (score 2):

I guess I figured it out. If you open the link, and then view the source, you will find the name of the source mp4 file.  Then you create a link like this:

http://archive-media.granicus.com:443/OnDemand/wilmington/wilmington_d31da0f6-c191-4b9d-a768-efe97d215f4f.mp4

Obviously you would change /OnDemand/Wilmington/ to whatever your municipality is.

Comment: Worked for a Sacramento council meeting!

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2024, the following process works for MacOS (and I assume Windows too):

1. Open the Granicus Player for the video you want to download (Example: https://sbcounty.granicus.com/player/clip/4503)
2. Open the Network tab in developer tools and search for the file extension ".m3u8" (you may need to refresh the page to see the request)
3. Copy the Request URL (Example:
   [https://archive-stream.granicus.com/OnDemand/\_definst\_/mp4:archive/sbcounty/sbcounty_29c1781c-4692-11ee-ae13-0050569183fa.mp4/playlist.m3u8](https://archive-stream.granicus.com/OnDemand/%5C_definst%5C_/mp4:archive/sbcounty/sbcounty_29c1781c-4692-11ee-ae13-0050569183fa.mp4/playlist.m3u8))
4. Open or [download VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)
5. Open VLC's Network Stream tool (File > Open Network on Mac) and paste the URL in the first field.
6. Check "Stream Output" and open the Settings to select your file location, name, and format.
7. Click "Open" to run

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLHATepF8fY

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2022, this method no longer works. I'll add a working solution when I find one.